# VS2010 for debugging com interop memory leaks

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, memory-leaks, com-interop, visual-studio-debugging

I know there have been some major improvements in Visual studio 2010 for debugging things like memory leaks from dump file etc. I wonder if it has any improvements specifically debugging memory leak for COM interop scenarios?

Comment: What language are you referring to? A lot of the debugging is specific to whether you are using managed or unmanaged code.

Comment: C# on managed side; COM is C++

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no specific way to test for memory leaks in unmanaged code in VS, especially from a managed host point of view. It gets even worse if you have no access to the unmanaged code.

My suggestion would be to create a bunch of instances of the COM object and repeatedly call its methods then dispose of the objects. If the memory usage just keeps increasing, there's probably a memory leak.

Then the *real* trick is to find it! There are a lot of ways to do this (way too many to enumerate here) so I'd suggest a quick Google for memory leak debugging tools.